# how to save array to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters

if i have params like this :

```
params["scholarship"] = {"name"=>"test", "state_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4"]}
```

and when i create object to database field state_id not save to database?

how to save to database with format :

```
#<Scholarship id: 1, name: "test", state_id: "["1", "2", "3", "4"]">
```

how do that?

thanks before

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[ActiveRecord::Base.serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799).

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :scholarship
end

user = User.create(:scholarship=> { "name" => "test", "state_ids" => ["1", "2"]})
User.find(user.id).scholarship# => { "name" => "test", "state_ids" => ["1", "2"] }
```

Comment: You should use the plural form for arrays: `state_ids`

Answer (score 41):

Also you can use PostrgreSQL support for array storing. (If you're using PG of course).
Your migration will look like that:

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, array: true, default: []
```

But don't forget about validations.

Answer (score 2):

In your model have

```
serialize :state_ids
```

Here is a [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) to the documentation

That being said it looks like you're trying to pass state_ids parameters and save it in state_id, is this what you're intending to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
state_ids != state_id
```

you've got 2 different names for your attribute, so they don't line up.
then use `serialize :state_ids` once you've renamed the column.

However if you're storing a list of state_ids, i'm going to guess you also have a states table, and so should look into using [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) association.

Comment: This is already corrected there.You should have responded there in the comment.Stick with the question