# How do I serialize an array field into MySQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have **request_type** as a array field in my database. For this I did following migration

```
def change
    change_column :users, :request_type, :string, array: true, default: '{}'
end
```

which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340222/how-to-save-array-to-database-in-rails).

I also added `serialize` into the model file.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  serialize :request_type, Array
  self.per_page = 15
end
```

A user can perform many requests, which I'm trying to store on their record in this format:

```
request_type: {"Discount", "Offer", "other options"}
```

I also tried to update them from console but it doesn't work there either.

```
a.request_type.push("offer")
```

getting `NoMethodError: undefined method push' for "[]":String` error.

When I try to add an item

```
a.request_type << "Offer"
```

the value becomes `"[]Offer"`

I know it is storing as string, so how can I update this field?

I am using rails 4, ruby 2.2.2, mysql.

**Edit** Stack trace

```
2.2.2 :016 > a = User.last
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 13, name: nil, email: nil, address: nil, mobile_number: "1234567890", client_id: 27, selected_option: nil, created_at: "2015-08-10 09:46:11", updated_at: "2015-08-10 09:46:11", ad_code: "1000014", request_type: "[]", sid: nil, circle: nil> 
2.2.2 :017 > a.request_type << "offer"
 => "[]offer" 
2.2.2 :018 > a.request_type.push("offer")
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for "[]offer":String
2.2.2 :008 > a.request_type << "offer".to_yaml
 => "[]--- offer\n...\n" 
2.2.2 :011 > a.request_type << "mnb".to_yaml
 => "[]--- offer\n...\n--- mnb\n...\n"
```

Comment: Have you tried just `a.request_type = ["Discount", "Offer"]` and `a.save` ? Also the `string` type of column not efficient, [because it's `255` length use `text` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354452/2057388)

Comment: yup, but getting ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "[]" error

Comment: try this `a.request_type = ["Discount", "Offer"].to_yaml` - [_The serialization is done through YAML._](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) but in Rails 4 it's should work without `.to_yaml`

Comment: also i suggest you try just `serialize :request_type` i use it for now without  a second option.

Comment: I tried your solutions but when I try to push another "xyz" into that `a.request_type` getting the issue.

Comment: according my suggestion, you are can't just `push(<<)` now, is only a one way to use it with `to_yaml` it's alway use it like `a.request_type = ["Discount", "Offer", "New value"].to_yaml`.

Comment: I have added console log.

Comment: Please show the result of `a.request_type = ["Discount"].to_yaml` __not__ `a.request_type << ["Discount"].to_yaml` nor `a.request_type << "offer".to_yaml`

Comment: I think serialize expects the database field to be `text` or `string` (text is safer).  Try changing the column type to be a text field, without the `array` option.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 4 with MySql serializes Arrays as YAML, but you've set the default to be `'{}'`, which can't be deserialized properly and remains a string. When I tested that way, I got the same result you did. Instead, in your migration, use `default: []` and let Rails will set the column default to the appropriately serialized YAML version.

This was tested in Rails 4.0.13, Ruby 2.2.2, MySQL 5.6.13:

```
class AddThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.string :items, array: true, default: []
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items
end
```

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| items | varchar(255) | YES  |     | --- []  |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
> t = Thing.new
 => #<Thing id: nil, items: []>
> t.items << 'a'
 => ["a"]
> t.save
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `things` (`items`) VALUES ('---\n- a\n')
> t = Thing.last
 => #<Thing id: 1, items: ["a"]>
> t.items = %w[a b c]
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
> t.save
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `things` SET `items` = '---\n- a\n- b\n- c\n' WHERE `things`.`id` = 1
 => true
> t.reload.items
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
```