# Rails database not updating array in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am trying to update an array held in the database however the update action is not working. The array is not updated and no error is shown. Other parameters in the form are correctly updated in the database.

A form sends an array as one of the parameters (in this case `responses: []`):

```
"task"=> {"title"=>"tasko uno", "responses"=>["yes", "no", "maybe", "other"] ... }
```

The update action:

```
def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update(tasks_params)
      redirect_to edit_task_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The params permissions:

```
private
    def tasks_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :help, :task_type, :taskflow_id, :responses => [])
    end
```

The database is the out the box sql-lite and the Task model has `serialize :responses, Array`, the array column is of type `text`, with a column title `responses`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT
The migration file:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :task_type
      t.text :help
      t.text :responses
      t.belongs_to :taskflow
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Update action server log:

```
Started PATCH "/tasks/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-28 12:37:12 +0100
Processing by TasksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BL2fI3JDIGfTqWxQHInR/NFI6N/agETaUb97lAZ86PpNmpj1ofQ+TRkHZNdiISyOMlag3geleig6PsaqaWNr8Q==", "task"=>{"title"=>"tasko uno", "help"=>"some help text", "task_type"=>"2", "taskflow_id"=>"1"}, "responses"=>["test1", "test2"], "commit"=>"Update Task", "id"=>"1"}
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Taskflow Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "taskflows".* FROM "taskflows" WHERE "taskflows"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/taskflows/1/edit
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

The form - I'm trying to have a form that adds fields dynamically:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :help %>
  <%= f.text_field :task_type %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :taskflow_id, value: @taskflow.id %>
  <hr>
  <p><strong>Responses</strong></p>

  <div class="admin-task-responses">
  <% if @task.responses %>
    <% @task.responses.each do |r| %>
      <%= render "tasks/task_response", {:res => r} %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="btn btn-primary add-response-btn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Response
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The partial:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :res %>
<div class="task-response form-group">
  <%= text_field_tag "responses[]", '', :class => 'form-control', :value => res %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340222/how-to-save-array-to-database-in-rails ?

Comment: @gen Thanks but i've already tried that - I'm using `serialize :responses` in the model and have checked `responses` is plural. It's not throwing an error so i'm having difficultly locating what's going on.

Comment: Please, add your server logs for the update action. Do you know how to use pry? You should examine your object after update.

Comment: Also post your migration for this column, and try to pass params without tasks_params method.

Comment: @gen thanks, I have added the migration file and the log for the update action. Passing params without task_params throws a forbidden attributes error. I will give pry a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"responses"=>["test1", "test2"]` is outside of the `tasks` hash, but on the other hand your `responses` field is a part of the Task model. Most likely, in your form you are using '..._tag' helper to enter your responses, and thus it is not connected to your @task, and it is the reason for not saving or at least for not getting any errors.

If you need more help on this, please add your form to the question.

OR, you can try the following, though, I would not recommend it over adjusting the form:

```
params[:task][:responses] = params[:responses]
```

This should work for you:

```
<%= text_field_tag "task[responses][]", '', :class => 'form-control', :value => res %>
```

Comment: ahh. Thank you! I am using text_field_tag in a partial to create a dynamic form that adds fields as required. I have posted the form if you caould help me do this in the correct way.

Comment: @RobotEyes; I updated my answer with a possible fix for you.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better, if you store "responses" in  json formate, so encode it in json and when required   decode it back.

so code would be some thing like bellow

```
private
params[:task][:responses] = params[:task][:responses].to_json
    def tasks_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :help, :task_type, :taskflow_id,   
      :responses )
    end
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the database is still not updating

Comment: this may be the case you have not added this field in attr_accessor, just like in model attr_accessor :responses

Comment: also have you removed [] from the response, it should be only :responses, also, what is data type for this field in db? it should be string, text ..

Comment: datatype in the db is `text`, column name is `responses`. Should I be adding a attr_accessor value to the model?

Comment: yes, you should add in model like attr_accessor :responses