# Can I have a way to customize field settings in rails activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to add a array field(named tags) in my sqlite database, so I have done some followings:

```
# migration
add_column :tags, :string

# controller
def update
  tags = params[:tags] # a array from frontend
  project.tags = tags.join(',')
  project.save!
end

def show
  project_hash = project.as_json
  project_hash['tags'] = project_hash['tags'].split(',')
  render json: project_hash
end
```

But I want to customize field setting and getting method directyly in active model, which is like below:

```
# model
def tags=(array)
  self.real_tags_column = array.join(',')
end

def tag
  self.real_tags_column.split(',')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It *should* work like this:

```
def tags
  self['tags'].split(',')
end

def tags=(array)
  self['tags'] = array.join(',')
end
```

If it doesn't, try `read_attribute`/`write_attribute`.

Comment: I think it works, get help from docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Overwriting+default+accessors

Comment: @Run: or that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Active record serialize attribute instead of customisation.

```
# Serialize a preferences attribute.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

# Serialize preferences using JSON as coder.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, JSON
end

# Serialize preferences as Hash using YAML coder.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, Hash
end
```

Please review [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) & [how to save array to database in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340222/how-to-save-array-to-database-in-rails)